# Laravel Sub-domain Routing Setup

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, subdomain, laravel-routing

I currently have a Laravel site up and running on Godaddy hosting.

What I want is to have a sub-domain.

mysite.xyz - main site

backoffice.mysite.xyz - admin

The main site is currently working.[image]

But the backoffice is not[image]

Here is my current routes file[image]

How do I make this work?

Edit.

Here are my routes according to php artisan route:list and it's correct. But my sub-domain route is still not working.
[image]

I've already created the sub-domain using cPanel and it's still not working.
[image]

Comment: Sorry, I live in SYdney and was off due to time offset. Did you solve this already?

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup the subdomain as well. You just created the domain and a route to the subdomain. You can create a subdomain using `ServerName subdomainname.domainname.com` in VirtualHost. Here is an example:  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/adding-a-subdomain-on-apache2

Comment: I'm sorry.I don't know how to do this. I'm using GoDaddy, WHM, and cPanel. Is there any way to do it using any of these 3? I'm new to domain subdomain configuration.

Comment: Godaddy instructions https://au.godaddy.com/help/how-do-i-create-a-subdomain-in-simple-control-panel-2290

Comment: still the same thing. I created the sub-domain using cPanel so I know it's ready. But it's still not showing up.

Comment: You know when your domain is setup, even if you dont have laravel, you can still access it. Same applies to subdomain. You can't even access it. Neither coud Laravel.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136808/discussion-between-paul-lucero-and-eddythedove).